# Hide DATEDIF result if cell data is empty

Tags: excel

I have a formula that checks DOB against when they started a job but if one of the fields isn't filled in it gives the number `116`. Is there a way I can hide the result if it equals `116` as it seems consistent across every `DATEDIF` formula?

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF([@[Date of Birth]],[@[Outcome Startdate]],"y"),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [COUNT function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c) to ensure that there are two dates to deal with.

```
if(COUNT([@[Date of Birth]],[@[Outcome Startdate]])=2, DATEDIF([@[Date of Birth]],[@[Outcome Startdate]], "y"), "")
```

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) handles errors and the DATEDIF is not throwing an error; it is returning **116**.